# Laravel 5.6 - eloquent many to many error 1066

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I've got a problem with a many to many relationship in my laravel 5.6 project. I've got some different many-to-many relationships already working but I can't find what is wrong in this one. I've tried google and stackoverflow already but couldn't find the answer.

So, I've got 3 tables; players, teams and players_in_teams
I would like to show a player and all the teams he is a part of.

This is my (simple) table layout:

**Teams**
- id
- teamName

**Players**
- id
- firstName
- lastName

**PlayersInTeams**
- id
- FKplayerID
- FKteamID

my code:

Player.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'firstName', 'lastName'
];

public function teams() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\PlayersInTeam', 'players_in_teams', 'FKteamID', 'FKplayerID');
}
}
```

Team.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['FKuserID', 'teamName', 'teamDescription', 'FKmediaID'];

public function players(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\PlayersInTeam', 'players_in_teams', 'FKteamID', 'FKplayerID');
}
}
```

PlayersInTeam.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PlayersInTeam extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['FKteamID', 'FKplayerID'];
}
```

PlayerController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $players = Player::all();
    return view('players.index', compact('players', $players));
}
```

showplayer.blade.php

```
<li>{{ $player->firstName.' '.$player->lastName }}</li>
<li>{{ $player->id }}</li>
@if($player->teams)
  <li>{{ $player->teams->id }}</li>
@endif
```

The full error i'm receiving:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'players_in_teams' (SQL: select `players_in_teams`.*, `players_in_teams`.`FKteamID` as `pivot_FKteamID`, `players_in_teams`.`FKplayerID` as `pivot_FKplayerID` from `players_in_teams` inner join `players_in_teams` on `players_in_teams`.`id` = `players_in_teams`.`FKplayerID` where `players_in_teams`.`FKteamID` = 1) (View: ../resources/views/players/showplayer.blade.php)

If hope someone sees what I'm missing,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of the functions are set to the pivot tables. You should set them to the final model. Try this:

```
public function teams() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'players_in_teams', 'FKplayerID', 'FKteamID');
}

public function players(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Player', 'players_in_teams', 'FKteamID', 'FKplayerID');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that in your migrations your **foreign keys** on your **joining table** are set properly. Something like this:

```
$table->foreign('FKplayerID')->references('id')->on('players')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
$table->foreign('FKteamID')->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```